# What's wrong with this shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a Bash script and its not executing throwing "num: command not found"

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "We will print Hello World a number of times."
    num=0
    while [ $num -lt 10 ]
    do    
    echo "Hello World!"
    num = $((num + 1))
    done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the whitespace around your second assignment to `num`. Remember that `var=` is recognized as assignment, but having any whitespace between the variable name and the `=` means it is interpreted as a command to be found on your `PATH`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "We will print Hello World a number of times."
num=0
while [ $num -lt 10 ]
do    
echo "Hello World!"
num=$((num + 1))
done
```

Comment: Why is whitespace a hindrance in execution?

Comment: @user1590011 Because that's how bash is designed? It's just because bash is set up to recognize one thing as assignment, and the other is a command. You might as well ask why programs are written in text and not in [colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_(programming_language)#Piet).

Comment: No I won't. You have explained it very nicely in your statements before the code. Thanks. I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line to

```
num=$(($num + 1))
```

Comment: Bash actually doesn't require the `$` inside of `(( ))`, if I recall.

Comment: @ChrisHayes you're right. It's just the space that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0
while [ "$num" -lt "10" ]
do
   echo "Hello World"
   num=$((num+1))
done
echo "Finished"
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are right, if you want assignment then you should use no spaces around `=`.
But it is worth mentioning that this script could be rewritten like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "We will print Hello World a number of times."
num=0
while (( num < 10 ))
do
    echo "Hello World!"
    ((num++))
done
```

Now it is much clearer for  reading. Want arithmetic expressions? Then use correct syntax!

Okay, but now we can notice that you're doing something very similar to [c-style for-loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for). That's how it can look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "We will print Hello World a number of times."

for ((num=0; num < 10; num++))
do
    echo "Hello World!"
done
```

Even better!